# Css not being applied to table class

Tags: css, css-selectors

We have a generic `table` element that is predefined in WordPress. I would like to define a class name to a table element and have it use the custom css.

*Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? We are using a CDN, which I can see the .cookie_table class inside the minified style.css*.

```css
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      border-radius: 0; }
      thead,
      tbody,
      tfoot {
        border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
        background-color: #fefefe; }
      caption {
        padding: 0.5rem 0.625rem 0.625rem;
        font-weight: 700; }
      thead {
        background: #f8f8f8;
        color: #8E908F; }
      tfoot {
        background: #f1f1f1;
        color: #8E908F; }
      thead tr,
      tfoot tr {
        background: transparent; }
      thead th,
      thead td,
      tfoot th,
      tfoot td {
        padding: 0.5rem 0.625rem 0.625rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-align: left; }
      tbody th,
      tbody td {
        padding: 0.5rem 0.625rem 0.625rem; }
      tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        border-bottom: 0;
        background-color: #f1f1f1; }
      table.unstriped tbody {
        background-color: #fefefe; }
        table.unstriped tbody tr {
          border-bottom: 0;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
          background-color: #fefefe; }
```

Table class:

```css
    .cookie_table {
        table {
            width: auto;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table has the classs `.cookie_table`, so the selector has to be `table.cookie_table { ... }` or just `.cookie_table { ... }` alone (less specific), but not `.cookie_table` as child of `table` like in your code (which BTW only would work at all if you use LESS or SASS)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either using table.cookie_table in the css or changing the class of table to an ID if possible.